# Daily data archival from Postgres to Hive/HDFS

Tags: postgresql, hive, hdfs, bigdata, sqoop

I am working on IOT data pipeline and I am getting messages every second from multiple devices into postgres database. Postgres will be having data for only two days and after two days data will be flushed so that every time there is data for last two days. Now I needed to do data archival from postgres to HDFS daily. The parameters I have are : 

**`deviceid, timestamp, year, month, day, temperature, humidity`**

I want to archive it daily into HDFS and query that data using hive query. For that I need to create **external partitioned table** in Hive using deviceid, year and month as partitions. I have tried following options but its not working:

1. I have tried using sqoop for data copying but it can't create dynamic folders based on different deviceid,year and month so that the external hive table can pick partitions
2. Used sqoop import using `--hive-import` attribute so that data can be copied directly into hive table but in this case it overwrites the existing table and I am also not sure whether this works for partitioned table or not

Please suggest some solutions for the archival.

**Note: I am using azure services so option for Azure Data Factory is open.**

Comment: you can also try sqooping the data to some location at hdfs and then later move to external partitioned table using Load data inpath statement with some static partition column name. such as current date etc.

Comment: Thanks @vikrantrana for replying on Sunday..:p  I have tried that but little differently. I have copied into hdfs and creating a hive table over it and then inserting data from this hive table into final partitioned external hive table but since I am having around 10K devices, this data goes into all 10K partition which is making it very slow. Taking half a day to complete it.

Comment: If you just want to move it into single partition on daily basis then load data inpath will work much faster as it just move the file to known partition location. You can then create a new partition and move file again as n when it comes or your sqoop job runs at scheduled time. Thanks

Comment: In my case there are around 10K partitions, what could be solution for this? What are the archival tools for these kinds of use cases.

Comment: i suggest/if possible, create a partitioned table with columns year,month,day and use bucketing sorted by deviceid number of buckets are based on your data size for two days. Load this partitioned table from another table so that it can create folders dynamically. Finally you will have folders in year/month/day, with this there will not be many folders and with bucketing you can gain some performance i believe! hope this helps!